# Why are there self-duplicating curly brackets in persisted WPF RichTextBox?

Tags: wpf, persistence, richtextbox

Our tester threw curly brackets at our persisting WPF RichTextBoxes.  On save and reopen, there are magically more curly brackets.

I've condensed the issue / code down.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <RichTextBox x:Name="rtb1" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click">Draw a fish</Button>
    <RichTextBox x:Name="rtb2" Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Two rich text boxes.  On button click, the bottom one gets set to the result of the first one after persist and restore.

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            rtb1.Document = new FlowDocument(new Paragraph(new Run("{")));
        }


        public static FlowDocument CreateFlowDocumentFromByteArray(byte[] byteArray)
        {
            return (FlowDocument)XamlReader.Load(new MemoryStream(byteArray));
        }

        public static byte[] CreateByteArrayFromFlowDocument(FlowDocument flowDocument)
        {
            MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = false;
            settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
            XamlDesignerSerializationManager dsm = new XamlDesignerSerializationManager(XmlWriter.Create(mStream, settings));
            dsm.XamlWriterMode = XamlWriterMode.Value;
            XamlWriter.Save(flowDocument, dsm);
            mStream.Close();
            return mStream.ToArray();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            rtb2.Document = CreateFlowDocumentFromByteArray(CreateByteArrayFromFlowDocument(rtb1.Document));
        }

    }
}
```

Why is this happening?  How do we stop it?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me -- I've reported it at Microsoft Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/WPF/feedback/details/563677/wpf-paragraphs-with-a-leading-curly-bracket-do-not-xamlwriter-save-correctly

Answer (score 1):

I'll test the code more thoroughly tonight, but does it happen when the braces are not at the start of the text? E.g., if your run was "Hello{World}" does it still do this?

As you probably know, curly braces are significant in WPF because they are used for markup extensions. The following markup wouldn't work:

```
<Button Content="{Hello}" />
```

To get the right output, you'd usually escape it with:

```
<Button Content="{}{Hello}" />
```

Since you're using XamlReader.Load, there may be some confusion around the use of {}'s in the XAML, so they are being escaped. But that's just a guess. Out of interest, what does the XAML which is written out look like?

Comment: It does only do it when it's at the start.  When you write it out, it does have {}{

Comment: To be more precise, this occurs only when the curly brackets are at the start of a paragraph.  We have a workaround (since we were already walking the tree applying styles) but it's just more overhead, and we are pretty frustrated that this happened at all.